# BlackBerry Smartphone WebWorks jQuery Tutorial

Tags: jquery, blackberry-webworks

I need to learn how to do mobile development using Webworks and jQuery but I am new to mobile programming and also Webworks. Does know any tutorials for beginners as I new to mobile programming, Webworks and Black

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are some links for that

[Porting jQuery functionality](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/porting_jquery_intro_1985571_11.html)

[Fundamentals Guide: From jQuery to WebWorks](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Fundamentals-Guide-From-jQuery-to-WebWorks/ta-p/1530269)